# How to store a dynamic python dictionary in MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, scrapy

I am doing a mini-project on Web-Crawler+Search-Engine. I already know how to scrape data using Scrapy framework. Now I want to do indexing. For that I figured out Python dictionary is the best option for me. I want mapping to be like **name/title of an object (a string)** -> **the object itself (a Python object)**.

Now the problem is that I don't know how to store dynamic dict in MySQL database and I definitely want to store this dict as it is!

Some commands on how to go about doing that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: how about a NoSQL database?

Comment: pyMongo is a simple way to do this

Comment: @LawrenceBenson: Can u elaborate briefly?

Comment: @hd1: I don't know it. If u could say some more about it, it 'd be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! Really appreciate it!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL ... something like mongo db is suited better for this usecase, as it stores information as key value pairs as a dictionary does. it's something really interessting to look into

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, a NoSQL solution would be more natural in this case. And since we are talking about schemaless dictionaries - a JSON document database such as MongoDB would be a good fit.

There is a [`scrapy-mongodb`](https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb) package that provides a pipeline into MongoDB database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store dynamic data in a database, here are a few options.  It really depends on what you need out of this.

First, you could go with a NoSQL solution, like MongoDB.  NoSQL allows you to store unstructured data in a database without an explicit data schema.  It's a pretty big topic, with far better guides/information than I could provide you.  NoSQL may not be suited to the rest of your project, though.

Second, if possible, you could switch to PostgreSQL, and use it's HSTORE column (unavailable in MySQL).  The HSTORE column is designed to store a bunch of Key/Value pairs.  This column types supports BTREE, GIST, GIN, and HASH indexing.  You're going to need to ensure you're familiar with PostgreSQL, and how it differs from MySQL.  Some of your other SQL may no longer work as you'd expect.

Third, you can serialize the data, then store the serialized entity.  Both `json` and `pickle` come to mind.  The viability and reliability of this will of course depend on how complicated your dictionaries are.  Serializing data, especially with `pickle` can be dangerous, so ensure you're familiar with how it works from a security perspective.

Fourth, use an "Entity-Attribute-Value" table.  This mimics a dictionaries "Key/Value" pairing.  You, essentially, create a new table with three columns of "Related_Object_ID", "Attribute", "Value".  You lose a lot of object metadata you'd normally get in a table, and SQL queries can become much more complicated.

Any of these options can be a double edged sword.  Make sure you've read up on the downfalls of whatever option you want to go with, or, in looking into the options more, perhaps you'll find something that better suits you and your project.